# Deploying Flask App on Heroku - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'

Tags: python, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a flask app to heroku. I have a `requirements.txt` file with the following packages that I generated through `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

```
autocorrect==2.4.0
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
dnspython==2.1.0
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
importlib==1.0.4
isodate==0.6.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
joblib==1.0.1
kiwisolver==1.3.1
llvmlite==0.36.0
lxml==4.6.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
nltk==3.5
numba==0.53.1
numpy==1.20.1
onelogin==1.9.1
pandas==1.2.3
Pillow==8.1.2
pprintpp==0.4.0
pymongo==3.11.3
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.15.0
python3-saml==1.10.1
pytz==2021.1
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.1
scikit-learn==0.24.1
scipy==1.6.1
six==1.15.0
sklearn==0.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tqdm==4.59.0
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
xmlsec==1.3.9
```

When I commit and push my repository, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'`. I am using the `heroku/python` build pack. I'm not sure what's causing this, and any advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

[image]